# Using Tesseract in a web based application where JDK is 64 bit

Tags: java, tomcat, tesseract

I am developing a web based OCR system using Tesseract.  My JDK is 64 bit.But when I run my project it gives the following error

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.ocr.TesseractOcr.performOcr(TesseractOcr.java:22).
```

But when I use Tesseract in standalone application, It extract text from images. I am using Tomcat as the server. And tess4j-3.0.jar is missing liblept172.dll

1. Can't I use Tesseract in 64 bit JDK?
2. How can I use Tesseract in Tomcat server
3. How can I add liblept172.dll to tess4j-3.0.jar file?
4. Are there any alternatives for tesseract which don't use dll files?

I went through almost all the tutorials related to this issue. But unfortunately non worked for me. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: Tess4J requires Lept4J library, which has `liblept.dll`.

Comment: Can't I used liblept172.dll which is used for 64 bit?

Comment: Yes, be sure to set `jna.library.path` variable to specify its location.

Answer (score 0):

using 32bit dll with 64bit java is not possible.
you must use the same architecture as the jvm for native dll.

If this is the case, a common jni issue is, if you set a dedicated "native library path" and have missing dependent dlls like libc or vcrt.

Also common is, that you place the lib ina path that is not examined. If you think you did all right, we used ProccessMonitor on Windows to find the missing dll file during init. You can follow the different locations the jvm is looking at, including filenames.

UPDATE: according to docs tess4j loads `libtesseract304.dll` on windows.

The docs also state, that the libs are included in the jars and extracted at runtime. This may require running as commandline tool. It furthermore uses jna https://jna.java.net/javadoc which is a jni wrapper to help with dll loading. It follows a jna.library.path.

I would suggest giving ProcessMonitor a try. Live is too short to try and error debug dll loading :-)

https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: Once tess4j is downloaded there are two seperate files for 32 bit dll and 64 bit dll. I used dlls in 64 bit folder. And I even changed the VM option even. But nothing change. I added all the dlls to the classpath even. Also I used depends.exe to find the dependent dlls of libtesseract304.dll. And I even added them to the class path

Comment: native libs are not loaded from the classpath but from java.library.path. if that is not explicitely set it defaults to PATH on windows

Comment: You may have another x32 dll in your path somewhere that is found first. Have you set jna or java library.path to one folder and copied all dlls there?

Comment: How can I find the java.library.path?

Comment: it is a system property set with -Djava.library.path=... on the cmdline.

Comment: Can I edit VM option i Netbeans in order to achieve this?

Comment: In NB, you can set `jna.library.path` in Project Properties > Run > VM Options.